# Vaadin: How to add META-INF/services to the war?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, war, vaadin7

I have a Vaadin 7 maven web project that has some annotations that create service definition on `META-INF/services`.

I added this to the pom so the annotations are processed:

```xml
<!-- Run annotation processors on src/main/java sources -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The files show within `target/classes/META-INF/services` but don't make it to the final war.

I tried adding the folder to the maven-war-plugin like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <packagingIncludes>target/classes/*</packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But then most of the Vaadin files don't make it into the war and it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html just to make sure your project structure is correct and double check what gets copied where.

Comment: The maven-compiler plugin automatically runs annotation processors for you. You don't need a special plugin for it. The processor just needs to be in the compiler class path - typically as a `provided` scope dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the approach from this unrelated answer: [Maven: include folder in resource folder in the war build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198100/maven-include-folder-in-resource-folder-in-the-war-build).

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>target/classes/META-INF/services</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>META-INF/services</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Basically added the services folder as a resource and placed it on the right place of the final war.

Answer (score 4):

Please see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

It looks like your `META-INF` folder is in `src/main/resources` directory.

Normally when creating a `WAR` you would create a directory `src/main/webapp` where you can have your `WEB-INF`, `META-INF` and other required folders.

```
 |-- src
 |   `-- main
 |       |-- java
 |       |   `-- com
 |       |       `-- example
 |       |           `-- projects
 |       |               `-- SampleAction.java
 |       |-- resources
 |       |   `-- images
 |       `-- webapp
 |           |-- META-INF
 |           |-- WEB-INF
```

Everything from your `webapp` folder will be copied over to the root dir in the `WAR`.

The path to your `webapp` can also be configured using **warSourceDirectory** property

## For your scenario - generated sources

Obviously you don't want to keep your generated sources in your `src/*` folder and don't want to version it.

You can get around this by either adding an ignore filter to your version control metadata; or by creating a symlink; or using `copy-resources` as some previous answers said, but not recommended.

You can achieve this by adding a `webResources` configuration to copy the generated sources from `target` folder by

Please see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
  <configuration> 
    <webResources> 
      <resource> 
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/target/generated-sources</directory> 
        <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath> <!-- introduced in plugin v 2.1 -->
        <includes> 
          <include>*.class</include> 
        </includes> 
      </resource> 
    </webResources> 
  </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: In my case it is not generated sources. Is a service definition file, but this is close enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<execution>
    <id>process</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${projectId}</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>relative project directory</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>path</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```